# Is there an API in Microsoft Azure where I can identify if a user is inactive or logged out of Tenant

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I could find a MS graph sign API which gives me last signin datetime but could not find API which can give me last signout time or how long a user is inactive.

Sign in API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

PLease can someone suggest how can I identify if a user is inactive or logged out of MS azure tenant

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can use [signInActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-1.0) property defined on the [user resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=Known%20issue.-,signInActivity,-signInActivity).

The Entra [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts) describes how to [detect inactive user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts#detect-inactive-user-accounts-with-microsoft-graph)

Comment: Thanks for responding, the docs says we have to use lastSignInDateTime attribute to identify if a user is inactive. I dont this this will help my usecase. Is there a attribute which givex lastlogout detail/time.   My usecase is suppose a user login at 1pm and not active after 3pm then i should be able to recognize that user and take action on it.